# Oracle APEX default components css customization

Tags: css, oracle-apex

I'm currently learning oracle apex and I'm familiar with html, css and javascript. I wonder if it's possible to customize the css of default components. If so could you point me to the right place in the development environment.

Comment: Oracle's APEX and Salesforce's Apex are not the same thing. Please clarify your question and remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572901/4178262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components generate CSS. For some, not all of them, you can alter the templates and customize the HTML.
Look and feel is dictated by the selected theme and associated templates. Predefined themes use predefined markup, css, even some javascript. Can you alter that? Yes. Should you? No. Copy it and make a custom theme? Yes. Still, you won't have full html control, ever.

Even so, CSS is just that, CSS. I don't see the issue. If you want to change some things, just add rules which would overrule those you don't like? If it goes further than that you'd be best served by creating your own theme.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue was in that I simply didn't known how to overrule the things I did't like. I wasn't even sure whether it was possible. Now that I know it's not a problem I will do my own research. Still any helpful links would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't really give any specifics. The method is just the same as ever: open up the browser's dev tools, inspect, find the rules, overrule them, save them in a file or put them inline on page/template level in apex. If you're familiar with css and web development that should sound familiar, and if not, I can only advise googling a bit on the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You can change a lot of stuff globally on the theme roller. Just run any page and it will show in the bottom right of the screen. You can change many things without having to code, but there is a place for global CSS

At the beginning of every page there a place for inline CSS for that page.

You can change the theme directly, but I don't reccommend doing that before knowing a lot of the tool.

It is also possible to add external files or to upload them in the shared contents section.