# Oracle Apex 5 - Footer bar like the one in App Builder

Tags: html, css, oracle, oracle-apex

How can I create a footer bar/region in a Oracle Apex Universal Theme Application just like the one in the Oracle Apex App Builder? What is the html/css code needed to achieve that? Specifically, i'm interested in change or substitute the one which already exists in the UT for something that resembles the one in the App Builder

[image]

I'm part of a team responsible for redesign the applications developed in early themes that weren't migrate to the Universal Theme, and some of them have informations to be displayed on the footer region. Since there is the necessity to migrate these applications to the UT, we would like to use a footer bar just like the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The Universal Theme page template includes a footer section:

```
    <footer class="t-Footer">
      #APP_VERSION#
      #CUSTOMIZE#
      #SCREEN_READER_TOGGLE#
      #REGION_POSITION_05#
    </footer>
```

It looks something like this:

[image]

One solution is therefore to create a region in Region Position 5, and this will be displayed after the other items in the footer.

You could also modify the template HTML to remove any/all of the existing footer info and add your own.  You would probably want to use references to page or application items - for example:

```
    <footer class="t-Footer">
      #SCREEN_READER_TOGGLE#
      #REGION_POSITION_05#
      &APP_MY_FOOTER_INFO.
    </footer>
```