# How to display logged in user id on page header in Oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to display the logged in user id on the header of the page. How to achieve this?

I can see app name on top left corner. I need to display logged in user id using a query on top middle part.

Comment: Have you tried &APP_USER.to display the user? Not sure where you want to place it exactly. Inside a region title, but than the user id on the middle while the rest remains on the left?

Comment: Create a entry in your top right menu and use &APP_USER. as label and link to a url and just # in the target.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572901/4178262

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about the page Template Header.

One way of doing it would be to create a new page template that you'll modify to include the USER_ID in the Header.

`"In your application"> Shared Components> User Interface> Templates`

There you should make a copy of whatever page template you're using (most probably the Standard Page from theme 42).

Select that template then under the `Definition` tab you should see the `Header` section, that is the HTML of the header of that Template.

```
    <div class="t-Header-logo">
      <a href="#HOME_LINK#" class="t-Header-logo-link">#LOGO#</a>
    </div>

    <!-- This is where you should insert what ever you want to add to you header -->

    <div class="t-Header-navBar">
      #NAVIGATION_BAR#
    </div>
```

As stated by @TMNuclear in his comment `&APP_USER.` refers to the current user so inserting something like:

`<div style="flex-grow: 1.2;"> &APP_USER. </div>`

Should do kinda what you want to do, you just need to style it how you want using CSS.

Then you need to set your new template in every page where you want it:

`"Your Page Item"> Appearance> Page Template > "Your Template"`

Answer (score 0):

You will find all the documentation for substitution strings at

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB03024

Consider the following examples:

From within an HTML region:

```
Hello you are logged in as &APP_USER.
```

Using PL/SQL:

```
htp.p('Hello you are logged in as'||V('APP_USER'));
```

As a bind variable:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE user_id = :APP_USER
```

Comment: And I would imagine the `&APP_USER.`  would have the best performance for this situation. (Don't forget the period at the end!)